# How to write output of a bash command in tabular format with a pre-defined spacing

Tags: bash, shell, cut, text-formatting

```
 2   0   0   184
 2   0   0   184
 765311      61423       6454323302  470948
 598500      678403      6454288800  1810469
```

I used `grep <command output> | cut -d ':' -f 3 | column -x >> $temp` to write data in tabular format. But there seem to be huge difference in length of strings which causes the table to skew. I need to format these with equal spacing. How can I do that?

Edit: The file that the command runs on contains text as following:

```
total_STDIO_OPENS: 176400
total_STDIO_FDOPENS: 0
total_STDIO_READS: 5881999200
total_STDIO_WRITES: 276435
total_STDIO_SEEKS: 0
total_STDIO_FLUSHES: 0
total_STDIO_BYTES_WRITTEN: 7689144
total_STDIO_BYTES_READ: 53954527200
total_STDIO_MAX_BYTE_READ: 917480
total_STDIO_MAX_BYTE_WRITTEN: 176
total_STDIO_FASTEST_RANK: 81759
total_STDIO_FASTEST_RANK_BYTES: 917712
total_STDIO_SLOWEST_RANK: 137230
total_STDIO_SLOWEST_RANK_BYTES: 917729
total_STDIO_F_META_TIME: 235319.135093
total_STDIO_F_WRITE_TIME: 2.271446
total_STDIO_F_READ_TIME: 1204.541221
total_STDIO_F_OPEN_START_TIMESTAMP: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_CLOSE_START_TIMESTAMP: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_WRITE_START_TIMESTAMP: 6.714122
total_STDIO_F_READ_START_TIMESTAMP: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_OPEN_END_TIMESTAMP: 6.782347
total_STDIO_F_CLOSE_END_TIMESTAMP: 6.856372
total_STDIO_F_WRITE_END_TIMESTAMP: 346.306913
total_STDIO_F_READ_END_TIMESTAMP: 6.856351
total_STDIO_F_FASTEST_RANK_TIME: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_SLOWEST_RANK_TIME: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_VARIANCE_RANK_TIME: 0.000000
total_STDIO_F_VARIANCE_RANK_BYTES: 0.000000
```

I am `grep`'ing using `grep -Ein 'total_stdio_read|total_posix_write|total_stdio_write|total_posix_read' $file | cut -d ':' -f 3 | column -x >> $temp`

Desired output is:

```
2           0           0           184
2           0           0           184
765311      61423       6454323302  470948
598500      678403      6454288800  1810469
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I am getting the output but I don't know how to format it.

Comment: Your sample input file only matches two lines with that grep pattern... something that produces results that match the numbers in your desired output would be useful.

Comment: It's a similar file just different numbers.

Comment: `column -t` might help.

Comment: nope for some reason it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what worked for me was mix of solutions.

`<command output> | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | column -x | xargs -n4 printf '%-10d  %-10d  %-10d  %-10d\n'`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want a length of 10 characters per column plus 2 characters extra spacing.
Increase the length if the data doesn't fit into the columns (data is not truncated).

`xargs` and `printf`:

```
$ <your commands> | xargs -n4 printf '%-10s  %-10s  %-10s  %-10s\n'
2           0           0           184
2           0           0           184
765311      61423       6454323302  470948
598500      678403      6454288800  1810469
```

---

`awk` and `printf`:

```
$ <your commands> | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-10s%s", $i, (i==NF ? ORS : "  ")}'
2           0           0           184
2           0           0           184
765311      61423       6454323302  470948
598500      678403      6454288800  1810469
```

---

Or simply `column -t`:

```
$ <your commands> | column -t
2       0       0           184
2       0       0           184
765311  61423   6454323302  470948
598500  678403  6454288800  1810469
```

Comment: %-10s doesn't print anything to the terminal for some reason so I tried replacing it with %-10d but that result in `expected a numeric value` error

Comment: You need one argument for each `%...` format option, e.g. in the first example there are four arguments on each line (`-n4`) and four `%-10s` format options and in the second example there are two of them (the actual value and spacing/newline).

Comment: by %-10s what I meant was %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s

Comment: I love `column -t`. Great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BASH 'printf' builtin. This has the same syntax for formatting as C printf() so there are many options.

Example:

```
$ printf "%-20s %3f\n" abc 3.4
abc                  3.400000
```